# Javascript: How to window.open with a html file on the server, but not a URL?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, popup

Is it possible to open a new window using a html file on the server? But the "myfile.html" can't be accessed on browser url?

```
<FORM>
<INPUT type="button" value="New Window!" 
onClick="window.open('./publico/myfile.html','mywindow')">
</FORM>
```

I'm using PHP with the ff workspace:
C:\workspace\myproject\publico\index.html

Or do you have any suggestion please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

No, not like in your example. `window.open` is JavaScript code that tells the user's web browser to open a window. the user's web browser can't access files on your server unless those files are available over the web, i.e. at a URL.

You might be able to use PHP to write out the document's contents in a JavaScript string, and then use JavaScript to add that content to the newly opened window.

Here's a very shonky example with JavaScript that pretty much seems to work in Chrome, but I'm sure the code can be improved, it might not be reliable cross-browser, and I don't know enough PHP to write that bit:

```
<script>
var newWindowContent = '<?php echo WHATEVER_PHP_CODE_WILL_WRITE_OUT_THE_HTML_PROPERLY_ESCAPED ?>';
</script>
<FORM>
<INPUT type="button" value="New Window!" 
onClick="var mywindow = window.open(); mywindow.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = newWindowContent;">
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

The webserver doesn't know if the browser wants to display the file in a specific window. That means it can't handle permissions depending on this.

When you want the user to be unable to access a specific file unless a specific condition is met, you could make that file a php file, set a cookie before requesting it, and make the php file return a 403 forbidden error code when this cookie isn't set and the content when it is (keep in mind that the user can forge cookies).